# Looking to generically convert JSON file to CSV in Python

Tags: python, json, nested-json

Tried solution shared in link :: [Nested json to csv - generic approach](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37706351/nested-json-to-csv-generic-approach)

This worked for Sample 1 , but giving only a single row for Sample 2.
is there a way to have generic python code to handle both Sample 1 and Sample 2.

Sample 1 ::

```
{
    "Response": "Success",
    "Message": "",
    "HasWarning": false,
    "Type": 100,
    "RateLimit": {},
    "Data": {
        "Aggregated": false,
        "TimeFrom": 1234567800,
        "TimeTo": 1234567900,
        "Data": [
            {
                "id": 11,
                "symbol": "AAA",
                "time": 1234567800,
                "block_time": 123.282828282828,
                "block_size": 1212121,
                "current_supply": 10101010
            },
            {
                "id": 12,
                "symbol": "BBB",
                "time": 1234567900,
                "block_time": 234.696969696969,
                "block_size": 1313131,
                "current_supply": 20202020
            },
        ]
    }
}
```

Sample 2::

```
{
    "Response": "Success",
    "Message": "Summary succesfully returned!",
    "Data": {
        "11": {
            "Id": "3333",
            "Url": "test/11.png",
            "value": "11",
            "Name": "11 entries (11)"
        },
        "122": {
            "Id": "5555555",
            "Url": "test/122.png",
            "Symbol": "122",
            "Name": "122 cases (122)"
        }
     },
    "Limit": {},
    "HasWarning": False,
    "Type": 50
}
```

Comment: I haven't looked in too close detail to sample 2, but doesn't pandas normalize JSON work for sample 2? Then you can push it into a dataframe and export into any format you like.

Comment: json_normalize does not work out of the box if you have lists somewhere in JSON

Comment: Agreed with Krishna, direct json_normalize doesn't support generically nested JSON files.

Comment: Tried using shared code, which works well for Sample1 data , but its generates single row as output with this generic code for Sample2 data

Comment: What is the error you are getting

Answer (score 0):

Try this, you need to install flatten_json from [here](https://pypi.org/project/flatten-json/)

```
import sys
import csv
import json
from flatten_json import flatten


data = json.load(open(sys.argv[1]))
data = flatten(data)

with open('foo.csv', 'w') as f:
    out = csv.DictWriter(f, data.keys())
    out.writeheader()
    out.writerow(data)
```

Output

```
> cat foo.csv
Response,Message,Data_11_Id,Data_11_Url,Data_11_value,Data_11_Name,Data_122_Id,Data_122_Url,Data_122_Symbol,Data_122_Name,Limit,HasWarning,Type
Success,Summary succesfully returned!,3333,test/11.png,11,11 entries (11),5555555,test/122.png,122,122 cases (122),{},False,50
```

Note: `False` is incorrect in Json, you need to change it to `false`

Comment: getting this error while trying to use flatten_json  "UnicodeDecodeError: 'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x8d in position 1001498: character maps to <undefined>". Looking for some generic code that can handle Sample data 1 and Sample data 2 both. flatten_json is unable to handle sample code 1

Comment: It's not because of the library. It's the encoding of the file you have issues with

Comment: HI Krishna , tried using utf8 , utf16, cp437 along with errors='ignore' as well. But still looking for a generic code  eg  like  :: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37706351/nested-json-to-csv-generic-approach which can handle both Sample Code 1 and Sample code 2 to convert from nested JSON file to CSV.

Comment: and even if we try to take sample code 2 in a string of data and apply the solution provided, it creates only a single row as output, we should be getting 2 rows as output of Sample code 2 JSON data.

Comment: Please share your expected output in each case

Comment: Expected Output of Sample code 1 ::   Response,Message,HasWarning,Type,Data.Aggregated,Data.TimeFrom,Data.TimeTo,Data.Data.id,Data.Data.symbol,Data.Data.time,Data.Data.block_time,Data.Data.block_size,Data.Data.current_supply
Success,,False,100,False,1234567800,1234567900,11,AAA,1234567800,123.282828282828,1212121,10101010
Success,,False,100,False,1234567800,1234567900,12,BBB,1234567900,234.696969696969,1313131,20202020

Comment: Expected Output of Sample Code 2:: Response,Message,Data,Id,Url,Symbol,Name,HasWarning,Type
Success,Summary succesfully returned!,11,3333,test/11.png,11,11 entries (11),false,50
Success,Summary succesfully returned!,122,5555555,test/122.png,122,122 cases (122),false,50